# Is it possible to embed a Youtube video in a CDF?

Tags: cdf-format

I'd like to embed a Youtube tutorial video inside a CDF.  I'm guessing this is not possible as my search for how to do this has been in vain.  I'm imagining an embedded Youtube video like one sees on a blog.

Comment: But you can embed a CDF and a YouTube video in a webpage.

Comment: I know I can do that but that's not what I want.  I want to embed helper videos and explanations within a notebook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible. Embedding a youtube video requires embedding some html into your webpage. CDFs are not constructed with html.

Comment: I know they aren't constructed with HTML but in the same way a web browser can render HTML it seems that Wolfram could allow an HTML cell that would allow this.  I hope it will become a feature in the future.  I was hoping there would be some other way of viewing a video from within a notebook.

Answer (score 0):

you can call a youtube video from within a notebook if you can access wi-fi where you're showing the notebook. here's an example:

SystemOpen["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IaO69CF5mbY"]

if you don't have wi-fi where you use the computer, you can download and save a youtube file on your computer and then just double-click on it it to run the video. see

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001002.htm